# Google glass php mirror api - Get results of scanned QR code

Tags: php, qr-code, barcode-scanner, google-mirror-api

Can anybody explain me how to get the result of Sacnned QR code in mirror api

Steps to produce :

1) Open any QR code and ask google glass to scan it

2) when user scans the code, it shows the result on a blank wghite screen like notepad

But i want to access the result and then store in my database and interact with mirror api on my web server.

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on glass and can tell you with whole responsibility - you can give it up. Why? because Google Glass does not support auto-focus which is vital to be able to scan QR code.

I spent few hours porting the Zxing app to glass and made it running - the auto-focus was the only reason it did not work. Auto-focus is a hardware feature, not software, so the only way to believe it will ever work - with the new version of glass.

Now on your question how to deliver data to mirror API - you can add subscriber on new items in timeline. publish the timeline item with the result of recognition - mirror api will get notification, then mirror API can delete timeline item by id.

The other way is to send the recognition result to simple (non mirror API) servlet and store it in database. later mirror API can use the stored data.